# In pygame I am trying to add the text as an integer and it keeps crashing, why?

Tags: pygame, text

I am trying to convert the string as an integer when I am using the `font.render()` function but it keeps saying different things like *it has to be a unicode or string* and so on. I am trying to display the scoreboard as text and in the right size the score which is getting +1 every time the snake gets the collision with the ball.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit 
import random


pygame.init()

#Creating the score font 
arial_font=pygame.font.SysFont("arial",20)
text=arial_font.render("Scoreboard", False, (255,0,0),(0,0,0))
#Creating the number score font
arial_font2=pygame.font.SysFont("arial",20)
score=arial_font2.render(scoreline, False, (255,0,0),(0,0,0))

#Score variable
scoreline=0

#Variables for the snake
step_len = 5
player=[(580,400)]
width=10
height=10
white=(255,255,255)
growing= False

#variabels for the ball
ball_width=110
ball_height=500

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
            
            
    #Screen Details
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    ball=pygame.draw.circle(screen,white,(ball_width,ball_height),3)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(10,0,1160,800),1)
    screen.blit(score,(300,400))
    def score():
        screen.blit(text ,(200,300))
        
            
            
    score()
    snake = None
    for i in range(len(player)):
        node = pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,(player[i][0],player[i][1],width,height),0)
        if i ==0:
            snake = node
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")
    
    
    #Keyboard input
    key_pressed=pygame.key.get_pressed()        

    playerx,playery = player[0][0],player[0][1]
    isMoved = True
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        playery-=step_len
    elif key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playery+=step_len
    elif key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerx-=step_len
    elif key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerx+=step_len
    else:
        isMoved = False
    
    if isMoved:
        #Limiting the snake in the box on x size
        if playerx >1160:
            pygame.quit()
        if playerx < 0:
            pygame.quit()
            
        #Limiting the snake in box on y size
        if playery >800:
            pygame.quit()
        if playery<0:
            pygame.quit()
        
        player.insert(0,(playerx,playery))
        #Colliding with the ball 
        if snake.colliderect(ball):
            scoreline+=1
            ball_width=random.choice(range(0,1160))
            ball_height=random.choice(range(0,700))
            
        else:
            player.pop(-1)
            
       
        
        
        
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is odd. e.g., in this code, you use a variable `scoreline` without it being initialized first.

```
arial_font2=pygame.font.SysFont("arial",20)
score=arial_font2.render(scoreline, False, (255,0,0),(0,0,0))
```

---

You're defining the `score` variable first as a surface (I think), so it would make sense to eventually use it like that `screen.blit(score,(300,400))`, like you're doing now.

The issue probably comes from the fact that you're overriding what `score` is. It was a surface, but after this code:

```
def score():
    screen.blit(text ,(200,300))
```

it is now a function, and so it can't be rendered.

I suppose this mess comes from the fact that you've been trying a couple of things that your gut told you.

[image]

Don't worry, we've all been there.

So I think that instead of what's here:

```
screen.blit(score,(300,400))
def score():
    screen.blit(text ,(200,300))
    
        
        
score()
```

you likely want something like this:

```
screen.blit(score,(300,400))
screen.blit(arial_font2.render(str(scoreline), False, (255,0,0),(0,0,0)),(200,300))
```

The key part here, is that the `render` function expects *text*, not an *integer*. You need to convert the content of `scoreline` to *text* before supplying it to the `render` function, and you do that by using the `str` python function.

I don't have access to pygame for now, but that should help you get started.

Comment: The gif gave me a chuckle. 